# Regex or perl code to count occurrences of a sequence inside an environment

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to detect the number of equation lines in a LaTeX document. So far, the best idea I've come to is to count the number of `\\` sequences (that mark a new line) inside equation environments. An example input would be

```
... text ...

\begin{align}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \\
    e &= f
\end{align}

... other text ...

\begin{eqnarray}
    x &= y \\
    z &= 1
\end{eqnarray}
```

The program should detect the three `\\` and thus return 5 as the total number of lines. 
There are a few possible equation environments in LaTeX, such as `align`, `align*`, `eqnarray`.

My question is how can I do this with regex and perl. I don't think this can be achieved with a single regex, however I was looking for a better solution than mine, which extract the text enclosed in a certain environment:

```
my @aligns = $texfile =~ /\\begin\{align\*?\}(.*?)\\end\{align\*?\}/sg;

foreach (@aligns) {
    my $count = () = $_ =~ /\\\\/g;
    $count++; #Lines are given by # of \\ + 1
    print "$count\n";
}
```

This snippet is repeated for each possible environment type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using a single regex. Here you need to back-refernce the captured characters by specifying the corresponding captured group index number like `\1`, which points the first group.

```
/\\begin\{(align\*?|eqnarray)\}(.*?)\\end\{\1\}/sg;
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/bW2xF4/2)

Comment: Great! Thanks. However, now also `align`  etc are captured and copied to the perl array. Is there a way to ignore the first capture group and only return the second one?

Comment: no it won't be possible. The string `align` must be captured. I think you could directly print the characters which are at group index 2.